# Parse / format local text file with FileReader on Javascript and HTML 5

Tags: javascript, css, html, dom

I'm trying to read a text file (log file) using HTML5 and JavaScript but I don't know how can I parse or format the text.

If I open the log file with text editor like Gedit or Sublime Text, I can see everything well formatted. But if I show the text on the screen through the HTML document the text has no order... I think the problem is due to line breaks...How I can force line breaks?

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" lang="es-es">
<title>Leer archivo de texto</title>

<style>
div {
margin-top: 30px;
border: solid 1px black;
padding: 5px;
}
</style>

<script>

function processFiles(files) {
var file = files[0];

var reader = new FileReader();

reader.onload = function (e) {
// Cuando éste evento se dispara, los datos están ya disponibles.
// Se trata de copiarlos a una área <div> en la página.
var output = document.getElementById("fileOutput"); 
output.textContent = e.target.result;
};
reader.readAsText(file);
}

</script>
</head>

<body>
<input id="fileInput" type="file" size="50" onchange="processFiles(this.files)">
<div id="fileOutput"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: messy text]

[image: Text well formatted using in a text editor]

Thank you so much guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you can accomplish what you're after by styling with `white-space: pre-line`

```
<div id="fileOutput" style="white-space: pre-line;"></div>
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space for more